# Why does my app crash when trying to retrieve data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and I'm trying to retrieve data from the Realtime Database of Firebase for my project, but whenever it reach to getting the data on the 
onClickFunction  the app crashes not sure why. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Firebase code

I'm following the tutorial from here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpWhAz3e1sI

I tried using implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3', and it still crashes

Firebase data

```
myfirebase-fbc55
|
|
    Movies
    |
    |
      movie1
          movieName: "The Angry Birds Movie 2"
          plot: "The Angry Birds Movie 2 (also referred to as An..."
      movie2
          movieName: "Good Boys" 
          plot: "Good Boys is a 2019 American comedy film co-wri..."
      movie3
          movieName: "Where'd You Go, Bernadette"
          plot: "Where'd You Go, Bernadette is a 2012 comedy nov..."
```

Android Studio Java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Log.d("working", "working ");
               db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Movies").child("movie1");
               db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String movie = dataSnapshot.child("movieName").getValue().toString();
                       String plot = dataSnapshot.child("plot").getValue().toString();

                       Log.d("movie", movie);
                       Log.d("plot", plot);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });
            }
        });
    }
```

Android Studio Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebasedemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm expecting the data to be shown in the log at least movie1, so I know that the app is retrieving the data correctly.

This is the error log

```
08-17 14:00:26.316 10148-10148/com.example.firebasedemo I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3>
08-17 14:00:26.317 10148-10148/com.example.firebasedemo I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3>
08-17 14:00:26.374 10148-10230/com.example.firebasedemo I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3>
08-17 14:00:26.376 10148-10230/com.example.firebasedemo E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider.produceIdTokenListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:85)
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider.addTokenChangeListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.deferredInitialization(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:109)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-17 14:00:26.381 10148-10148/com.example.firebasedemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-17 14:00:26.382 10148-10148/com.example.firebasedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebasedemo, PID: 10148
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@2736e3ff rejected from com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1@210f5cc[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:592)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop.scheduleNow(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:105)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.scheduleNow(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:276)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.addEventRegistration(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:233)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:149)
        at com.example.firebasedemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-17 14:00:28.418 10148-10148/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10148 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You are using a fairly old version of the Firebase Realtime Database client SDK.  Try upgrading everything to the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make sure in the 'Rules' section of Firebase Database 'read' & 'write' permissions are true, if not then make them true. And where you getting your values before that put a validation by checking if dataSnapshot is null. Like below:

```
db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       if(dataSnapshot != null) {
                           String movie = dataSnapshot.child("movieName").getValue().toString();
                           String plot = dataSnapshot.child("plot").getValue().toString();

                           Log.d("movie", movie);
                           Log.d("plot", plot);
                       } else {
                           Log.d(TAG, "Data Snapshot is null");
                       }

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });
```

By doing this you will know you are receiving any data or not. And don't forgot to check the permissions in 'Rules' section of your Firebase Database.

Comment: Hello, I did what you told me. The rules are already true and adding the if else statement is still causing my app to crash